# How to convert a binary file to a text file, containing ints and chars

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a binary file that is of size (sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)) times the number of nodes in the binary tree. The int is the data stored at each node, and the char is the operation performed once you reach that part in the file. (i for insert and d for delete) I just need to know how to convert the binary file to a text file for testing purposes.

The output should look something like this:

```
10 i
9 i
14 i
12 i
9 d
```

So far my program looks like this:

```
void convert(char * input, char * output)
{
    FILE * fpin = fopen(input, "rb");
    FILE * fpout = fopen(output, "w");

    char * oper; // operation (either 'i' or 'd')
    int key;   // information to be held by a node

    while ((fscanf(fpin, "%d%s", &key, oper) == 2) {
        fprintf(fpout, "%d %s\n", key, oper);
    }

    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);
}
```

However, I get a warning saying that oper may be used uninitialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change `char *oper` to `char oper`. It should not be a pointer.

I would suggest using `fread` instead. It is just to read a fixed number of bytes. Replace the while with this:

```
while(1 == fread(&key, sizeof key, 1, fpin) &&
      1 == fread(&oper, sizeof oper, 1, fpin)) {
      // Print the values
}
```

I recommend printing to stdout until you get result you want. The just change fo fpout.

However, keep in mind that your code is not portable. The size of an int can vary from machine to machine.

Comment: @Dipstick all files are binary.

Comment: @Dipstick No :)